# Discord Bot Stops Processing Commands When I Add An Keyword Event

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add a feature to my bot which would send messages if it detects a keyword.
Such as,
keyword = ["Hello There"]
User: Hello There
\Bot: Hi!

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
.
.
.
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author == client.user:
        return
    keywords = ["Hey","","Hi","Hello"]
    channel = ctx.channel
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword.lower() in ctx.content.lower():
            response = ("Hello sir!")
            await channel.send(response)
```

I am using this code for that but whenever I add this part to my code, other commands fail to proccess however this and other events are totally working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `await client.process_commands(ctx)` at the end of `on_message()` to put the message through to the `@client.command()` section.

Comment: You have to use whatever argument is passed to on_message(): in your case it seems like you've used ctx.